# Why is average-case complexity analysis considered hard?

Tags: time-complexity

Why is average case analysis considered more difficult than both best and worst case analysis? Specifically,  how do you approach  and complete best and worst case analysis as opposed to average case?

Thanks!

Comment: Your "specifically" question isn't a more specific version of the previous question. In fact, it's an impossibly broad question equivalent to, "And how do you do any complexity analysis that isn't average-case." I suggest you remove that part because it isn't really answerable except by writing a substantial book.

Comment: Intuitively, when you compute best / worst case complexity, you only need to know how your algorithm behaves on those specific cases. If you want to compute the average complexity, you "need" to know how it behaves on all (or at least most) instances and then compute the average.